# WPF RichTextbox remove Foreground information from TextRange

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, dependency-properties

sorry for my bad english... The default for a `RichTextBox` content is to inherit the Foreground color from the `RichTextBox` itself. That's nice, but if I set a specific `Foreground` color to some part of my text, that part does not inherit the `Foreground` anymore, obviously. How can I make my "colored" text inherit the `Foreground` again? I'm trying to do something like the "Automatic" color from Office Word but after I have set a specific color to a `TextRange`, I do not know how to unset it :/

`TextRange.ClearAllProperties()` does what I need, but also erases other properties like `FontSize` and `FontFamily`...

`TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(ForegroundProperty, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)` also does not do the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed almost impossible to achieve since there is no "RemovePropertyValue" method. I also tried with span and got the same exception as you did so I made a method that collects all the Paragraphs within the TextRange and made a span for each separetly.. less than ideal, I know.. Anyway, it works for a small example but might be pretty hard to work with for something more complex.

```
private List<Span> m_spanList = new List<Span>();

private void c_setForegroundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextPointer textPointerStart = c_richTextBox1.Selection.Start;
    TextPointer textPointerEnd = c_richTextBox1.Selection.End;
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(textPointerStart, textPointerEnd);
    SetForeground(textRange);
}

private void c_clearForegroundButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Span span in m_spanList)
    {
        span.ClearValue(Span.ForegroundProperty);
    }
}

public void SetForeground(TextRange textRange)
{
    List<Paragraph> spannedParagraphs = new List<Paragraph>();
    if (textRange.Start.Paragraph != null)
    {
        TextRange curRange = null;
        Block cur = textRange.Start.Paragraph;
        do
        {
            spannedParagraphs.Add(cur as Paragraph);
            // Get next range
            curRange = new TextRange(cur.ContentStart, cur.ContentEnd);
        } while ((textRange.End.Paragraph == null || !curRange.Contains(textRange.End.Paragraph.ContentEnd)) && (cur = cur.NextBlock) != null);
    }

    if (spannedParagraphs.Count == 1)
    {
        Span span = new Span(c_richTextBox1.Selection.Start, c_richTextBox1.Selection.End);
        span.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        m_spanList.Add(span);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spannedParagraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == spannedParagraphs.Count - 1)
            {
                Paragraph paragraph = spannedParagraphs[i];
                // For some reason I get an exception here when I try this..
                //m_span = new Span(paragraph.ElementStart, c_richTextBox1.Selection.End);
                c_richTextBox1.Selection.Select(paragraph.ElementStart, c_richTextBox1.Selection.End);
                Span span = new Span(c_richTextBox1.Selection.Start, c_richTextBox1.Selection.End);
                span.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                m_spanList.Add(span);
            }
            else if (i == 0)
            {
                Paragraph paragraph = spannedParagraphs[i];
                Span span = new Span(c_richTextBox1.Selection.Start, paragraph.ElementEnd);
                span.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                m_spanList.Add(span);
            }
            else
            {
                Paragraph paragraph = spannedParagraphs[i];
                Span span = new Span(paragraph.ElementStart, paragraph.ElementEnd);
                span.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                m_spanList.Add(span);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the result of your code is exactly what I need, but that wasn't exactly what I was looking for. In my case the user create the text (on a richTextbox), so he can select more than just a specific paragraph (or only part of it). I already tried to create a Span from the selected textRange and "ClearValue(ForegroundProperty)" all the inlines of that span but if the user select more than one pargraph I get the error: "'start' and 'end' TextPointers are not in the same Paragraph." :(

Comment: Meleak, thanks... your code did the trick. I will take a look on the most complex documents but for now I think it will work fine.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I think the answer you are really looking for is the answer by @jmlumpkin below.

Answer (score 5):

You can also unset it by setting the property to null (this worked for me clearing out the background, for example removing highlighting)

TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, null);

Comment: This does not clear the indicated DependencyProperty, it only sets it to null, which in case of the background is visually the same as a fully transparent brush, but gets problematic for foreground, which makes the text disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code of method `TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue` in the .NET Reference Source, you'll see that in the end it calls `DependencyObject.SetValue` on a collection of `Inline`s and `Block`s, and `DependencyObject.SetValue` treats the value `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` specially by effectively clearing the local value for the property.

The problem is that they didn't think of that when implementing `TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue`: it checks the passed property value against the property type, and in case of a reference type, it makes sure the passed value is either null or inherits from the same class, thus preventing us from passing `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

One solution I found to implement a way of clearing local values of a `TextRange` for dependency properties of a **reference type** is the following:

```cs
// We declare a marker brush to be detected later in the TextRange.
var markerBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

// First we ask the TextRange implementation to set our marker brush on its content.
// Using ApplyPropertyValue here takes care of splitting inlines when necessary to make
// sure that only the selected text gets affected.
range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, markerBrush);

// Now, we search the text range for every Inline that has our brush set as the foreground
// brush, and we clear the Foreground dependency property.
var position = range.Start;
while (position != null && range.Contains(position))
{
    if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Backward) == TextPointerContext.ElementStart &&
        position.Parent is Inline inline &&
        inline.ReadLocalValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty) == _foregroundClearBrush)
        inline.ClearValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty);
    position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
}
```